# Разбор вывода командной строки по отчету синхронизации времени Windows Time

Tags: windows, bat

Возникла задача мониторить сколько времени прошло с последней синхронизации времени. На сервере настроена слубжа Windows Time и синхронизация времени каждые N минут. По запуску команды

```
w32tm /query /status
```

можно увидеть время последней синхронизации:

```
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.1257607s
Root Dispersion: 7.8062967s
ReferenceId: 0xB869B607 (source IP:  1.1.1.1)
Last Successful Sync Time: 17/08/2020 13:17:13
Source: pool.ntp.org,0x1
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)
```

В конечном итоге нужно получить bat файл, который будет возращать значение в секундах, которое показывает разницу между текущим временем и временем последней синхронизации.

Например, если сейчас 17/08/2020 13:18:54 файл должен вернуть 101.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Перевод на русский завершен )

Comment: Я бы начал смотреть в сторону пошика. https://evlanoff.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/how-to-update-time-and-from-powershell/

Comment: А Вам точно надо на batch? Для этого надо использовать функции на подобие **[tdiff](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-tdiff.html)**. А вот на PS можно короче **powershell -Command "(new-timespan ([system.datetime]::ParseExact('17/08/2020 13:17:13','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null))).TotalSeconds"**

Comment: Кстати "PowerShell Module for Time Synchronization" от Rudolf Vesely (для работы со службой времени) данные о времени последней синхронизации тоже получает из командной строки утилитой w32tm. Поэтому если надумаете с помощью batch получать значение. То вот Вам для примера команда: **for /f "tokens=5*" %%a in ('w32tm /query /status^|find/i"Time"') do @echo %%a %%b**